# Trouble with multi-parameter if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, onclick

I have some basic HTML and JavaScript that will allow a user to click on one image of four images per each question that applies to them (a survey). Then, based on which two images the user clicked on, a link will be generated to rout them to another page. I decided that the easiest way to achieve this function would be through a series of 'if-statements' and making the clicked image ids 'false'.

**However my issue is**: I can get each individual false statement to work, but the combined statement will not trigger the alert.

**my HTML:**

```
<div id="page3">
<h1 align="right">generally i feel</h1>
   <img src="../Images/tile1.png" id="tile1" value="1"/>
   <img src="../Images/tile2.png" id="tile2" value="2"/>
   <img src="../Images/tile3.png" id="tile3" value="3"/>
   <img src="../Images/tile4.png" id="tile4" value="4"/>
</div>

<div id="page4">

<h1 align="right">i see</h1>
   <img src="../Images/ink.png" id="ink">
   <div id="pg4ans">
       <img src="../Images/tile5.png" id="tile5" class="tile2">
       <img src="../Images/tile6.png" id="tile6" class="tile2">
       <img src="../Images/tile7.png" id="tile7" class="tile2">
       <img src="../Images/tile8.png" id="tile8" class="tile2">
   </div>

</div>
```

**my Script:**

```
var dest1 = document.getElementById("tile1");
var dest5 = document.getElementById("tile5");

$('#tile1').click(function(){
    dest1 = false;
});

$('#tile5').click(function(){
    dest5 = false;
});

if(dest1 = false, dest5 = false){
    alert("link will replace this alert");  

}
```

Of course, if there is a simpler way to achieve this effect, that would be great too.

Comment: Try using two `=` in your combined if statement. The single `=` you are using now is assigning false, instead of checking for false.

Answer (score 2):

You need to think about scope.  Your statement

```
if(dest1 = false, dest5 = false){
    alert("link will replace this alert");  
}
```

is executing *immediately*, NOT after your click functions have executed.

Try wrapping the `<img>`s you want to monitor with an element and give that element a class, like this:

```
<div class="checkThese">
    <img src="../Images/tile5.png" id="tile5" class="tile2">
    <img src="../Images/tile6.png" id="tile6" class="tile2">
    <img src="../Images/tile7.png" id="tile7" class="tile2">
    <img src="../Images/tile8.png" id="tile8" class="tile2">
</div>
```

ten attach a handler to that div like so:

```
var clicked = [];

$('div.checkThese').on('click', function (e) {
    var thisImage = e.target.id;

    if (clicked.indexOf(thisImage) < 0) {
        clicked.push(thisImage);
    }

    check();
});

function check () {
    // This will run every time an image is clicked, and 
    // "clicked" contains the ids of all the images that
    // have been clicked
}
```

This is called [Event Delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate).

Comment: I think the if is happening in a different part of the code, and is only included in that spot for reference, though I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

### Correcting the `if` statement

Your `if` statement, as is, will always evaluate to `false`.  That's because it's a compound **assignment** statement (uses the assignment operator `=`) and the value of an assignment statement is the right-most value (`false`).  Additionally, this assignment statement is changing the values of `dest1` and `dest2`, setting both to false.

You want to use a **comparison** statement.  This requires using the comparison operator `==` (or `===`) to check if the two values are equal.  You can make this a compound statement by combining the two comparisons using the boolean AND operator `&&`.

Your full `if` condition then looks like this: `if(dest1 == false && dest5 == false)`

### Correcting execution order

Even after correcting the `if` statement, it will always return `false`.  That's because your code at the beginning sets your two variables to DOM elements:

```
var dest1 = document.getElementById("tile1");
var dest5 = document.getElementById("tile5");
```

Immediately afterwards, you set up click handlers:

```
$('#tile1').click(function(){
    dest1 = false;
});

$('#tile5').click(function(){
    dest5 = false;
});
```

However, the inner functions **do not run**.  They are just set up to run when the elements are clicked.  And immediately after that the `if` statement executes and because `dest1` and `dest2` are set to the tile DOM elements, they do not equal `false` and therefore the if statement will return false.

Clicking one of the tiles will change the value of `dest1` or `dest2`, but does not cause the `if` statement to be executed again.  You will never get the alert with your current code.

You'll need to call the `if` statement from each click handler, and as such, I recommend wrapping it in a named `function` so that it can be called and not duplicated 8 times over.  And assuming that you have a unique link for each combination, the `if`-`else if` chain will be 16 conditions long.  You definitely don't want to duplicate that.  Instead do something like the following (which will also allow the user to answer in any order):

```js
var dest1 = document.getElementById("tile1");
var dest5 = document.getElementById("tile5");

$('#tile1').click(function(){
    dest1 = false;
    check();
});

$('#tile5').click(function(){
    dest5 = false;
    check();
});

function check() {
    if(dest1 == false && dest5 == false){
        alert("link will replace this alert");  
    }
}
```

```css
img { cursor:pointer }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page3">
<h1 align="right">generally i feel</h1>
   <img src="http://www.iconsfind.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/20131105_527864817722b.png" id="tile1" value="1"/>
   <img src="http://www.iconsfind.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/20131105_5278647a8cc0e.png" id="tile2" value="2"/>
   <img src="http://www.iconsfind.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/20131105_5278647484ff1.png" id="tile3" value="3"/>
   <img src="http://www.iconsfind.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/20131105_5278646e40a39.png" id="tile4" value="4"/>
</div>

<div id="page4">

<h1 align="right">i see</h1>
   <div id="pg4ans">
       <img src="http://www.iconsfind.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/20131105_52786468beae1.png" id="tile5" class="tile2">
       <img src="http://www.iconsfind.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/20131105_52786462d44f8.png" id="tile6" class="tile2">
       <img src="http://www.iconsfind.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/20131105_5278645aa8bbc.png" id="tile7" class="tile2">
       <img src="http://www.iconsfind.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/20131105_52786454d3403.png" id="tile8" class="tile2">
   </div>

</div>
```

Once this is working, I'd highly recommend posting your full code (with all tiles working) to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) as I'm seeing a number of improvements that could be made that are outside the scope of this question.

Comment: thank you for such a thorough response; your suggestion worked swimmingly! And as you recommended, I will post the full code as this is just a small exemplary piece of segment. The actual code will have a series of 4 of these questions and without some help, will become hugely code intensive. Also, as you may notice in the full code, the selection process will be linear, so order will be less important, thank you for the suggestion regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var dest1 = true;
var dest5 = true;

$('#tile1').click(function(){
    dest1 = false;
    if(dest1 == false && dest5 == false){
        alert("link will replace this alert");  
    }
});

$('#tile5').click(function(){
    dest5 = false;
    if(dest1 == false && dest5 == false){
        alert("link will replace this alert");  
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tsq8o59s/)

Comment: Did you just delete your -3 answer and re-answer with the exact same thing?  This *wont* work if the user clicks `tile5` then `tile1`.

Comment: I recognize that I was wrong, then I decided to edit my previous answer with the 3 downvote and boommmm, it's disabled

Answer (score -1):

Try using two = in your combined if statement. The single = you are using now is assigning false, instead of checking for false.

```js
var dest1 = false;
var dest5 = false;
if(dest1 == false && dest5 == false)
{
    alert("link will replace this alert");  
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the problem that `dest1` and `dest2` will never be `false` when this code runs if they exist on the page.

Answer (score -1):

You have quite a few issues here.

In javascript comparison is done with `==` and `===` (strict equals).

`=` assigns a value .

### In this example:

```
if(dest1 = false, dest5 = false){
    alert("link will replace this alert");  
}
```

### you are actually doing:

```
if(false, false){
    alert("link will replace this alert");  
}
```

But a better approach would be something like this

```js
$('.page').on('click', 'img', function(){ 
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});

$('.page').on('click', '.done', function(){ 
   var $selected = $(this).parents('.page').find('img.selected');
   var values = $.map($selected, function(el){
     return $(el).attr('value');
   });
   $("#result").text(values.join(', '));
});
```

```css
img.selected {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page3" class="page">
   <h1>generally i feel</h1>     
   <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" id="tile1" value="1"/></a>
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" id="tile2" value="2"/>
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" id="tile3" value="3"/>
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" id="tile4" value="4"/>
     
   <button class="done">All done!</button>
</div>

<textarea id="result"></textarea>
```